# Is it grammatical to say "Are you done yet?"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it grammatical to say "Are you done yet?" or is it only correct to say "Are you done?" or something like "Have you done it yet?"?

Comment: All three are grammatical, they have slightly different nuances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Be done*** is an idiomatic phrase and it means:

> To be finished or ***have completed*** something.
>
> - I hope you're done writing that paper because class starts in three minutes. ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+done))

I underline again that ***to be done*** can mean ***to have completed***, so the idiom contains the aspect of the present perfect tense. So

> Are you done yet?

which can be rewritten as

> Have you completed [smth]/finished yet?

makes perfect sense.